# React Helmet only loads script on index page but not on other pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I am using Gatsby.js as my starter template.

I have a Layout.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import useSiteMetadata from './SiteMetadata'
import { withPrefix } from 'gatsby'
import './all.sass'
import './styles/blogs.sass'

const TemplateWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const { title, description } = useSiteMetadata()
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <html lang="en" />
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={description} />

        <link
          rel="icon"
          sizes="180x180"
          href={`${withPrefix('/')}img/wf-logo.png`}
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          href={`${withPrefix('/')}img/wf-logo-32.png`}
          sizes="32x32"
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          href={`${withPrefix('/')}img/wf-logo-16.png`}
          sizes="16x16"
        />

        <link
          rel="mask-icon"
          href={`${withPrefix('/')}img/safari-pinned-tab.svg`}
          color="#0288d1"
        />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#fff" />

        <meta property="og:type" content="business.business" />
        <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
        <meta property="og:url" content="/" />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content={`${withPrefix('/')}img/3d-desktop-backgrounds.jpg`}
        />
        <script src="../helpers.js" type="text/javascript" />
      </Helmet>
      <Navbar />
      <div>{children}</div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default TemplateWrapper
```

Also 2 pages:

```
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { frontmatter } = data.markdownRemark

  return (
    <Layout>
      <IndexPageTemplate
        image={frontmatter.image}
        title={frontmatter.title}
        subheading={frontmatter.subheading}
        mainpitch={frontmatter.mainpitch}
        intro={frontmatter.intro}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}


const BlogPost = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark: post } = data;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <BlogPostTemplate
        content={post.html}
        contentComponent={HTMLContent}
        description={post.frontmatter.description}
        helmet={
          <Helmet titleTemplate="%s | Blog">
            <title>{`${post.frontmatter.title}`}</title>
            <meta
              name="description"
              content={`${post.frontmatter.description}`}
            />
            <script src="../helpers.js" type="text/javascript" />
          </Helmet>
        }
        tags={post.frontmatter.tags}
        title={post.frontmatter.title}
        from={'blog'}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

As you can see here, both 2 pages have Layout as a wrapper, I have a script called: `helpers.js`
The React Helmet only injects this script on home page which is Index page if I open my website from the home page, but not for the Blog page.

For Index page:

[image]

For Blog page:

[image]

One thing worth mentioning is: if I open the home page first, then navigate to Blog page via the navigation links inside hamburger bar, then the `helpers.js` will stay there. Directly opening a page other than home page will not load `helpers.js`.

### Update

After moving Helmet from inside of BlogPostTemplate to in-between Layout and BlogPostTemplate, the whole blog page gone.

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { kebabCase } from "lodash";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby";
import { DiscussionEmbed } from "disqus-react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Content, { HTMLContent } from "../components/Content";
// import ImportMyScript from "../hooks/importMyScript";

export const BlogPostTemplate = ({
  content,
  contentComponent,
  description,
  tags,
  title,
  // helmet,
  from,
}) => {
  const PostContent = contentComponent || Content;
  const disqusConfig = {
    shortname: process.env.GATSBY_DISQUS_NAME,
    config: { identifier: title },
  };

  return (
    <section className="section">
      {/* {helmet || ""} */}
      <div className="container content">
        <div className="columns">
          <div className="column is-10 is-offset-1">
            <h1 className="title is-size-2 has-text-weight-bold is-bold-light">
              {title}
            </h1>
            <p>{description}</p>
            <PostContent content={content} />
            {tags && tags.length ? (
              <div style={{ marginTop: `4rem` }}>
                <h4>Tags</h4>
                <ul className="taglist">
                  {tags.map((tag) => (
                    <li key={tag + `tag`}>
                      <Link to={`/tags/${kebabCase(tag)}/`}>{tag}</Link>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            ) : null}
            {from !== "preview" ? <DiscussionEmbed {...disqusConfig} /> : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

BlogPostTemplate.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  contentComponent: PropTypes.func,
  description: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  helmet: PropTypes.object,
};

const BlogPost = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark: post } = data;
  // ImportMyScript("../helpers.js");
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Helmet titleTemplate="%s | Blog">
        <title>{`${post.frontmatter.title}`}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={`${post.frontmatter.description}`} />

        <BlogPostTemplate
          content={post.html}
          contentComponent={HTMLContent}
          description={post.frontmatter.description}
          tags={post.frontmatter.tags}
          title={post.frontmatter.title}
          from={"blog"}
        />
      </Helmet>
    </Layout>
  );
};

BlogPost.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    markdownRemark: PropTypes.object,
  }),
};

export default BlogPost;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostByID($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        title
        description
        tags
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

It does load the helpers.js but my blog page now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the `@reach/router` (React routing). It only loads the component that changes for each page/component. Since your `<Layout>` is shared for all pages, it only refreshes what's inside `children` because nothing is changing in the `<Layout>` component itself, just their own children `props`.

One approach that may work is to use a custom component with your `<Helmet>` inside and load it as well as in your `IndexPage` and `BlogPost`. Something like:

```
const BlogPost = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark: post } = data;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Helmet titleTemplate="%s | Blog">
        <title>{`${post.frontmatter.title}`}</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content={`${post.frontmatter.description}`}
        />
        <script src="../helpers.js" type="text/javascript" />
      </Helmet>

      <BlogPostTemplate
        content={post.html}
        contentComponent={HTMLContent}
        description={post.frontmatter.description}
        tags={post.frontmatter.tags}
        title={post.frontmatter.title}
        from={'blog'}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { frontmatter } = data.markdownRemark

  return (
    <Layout>
          <Helmet>
            <script src="../helpers.js" type="text/javascript" />
          </Helmet>
      <IndexPageTemplate
        image={frontmatter.image}
        title={frontmatter.title}
        subheading={frontmatter.subheading}
        mainpitch={frontmatter.mainpitch}
        intro={frontmatter.intro}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, what I would recommend but I'm not sure if it fits your requirements is to use a [`gatsby-browser.js` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/browser-apis/). Gatsby exposes multiple APIs there and one of the methods allows you to load a script in all your pages. It should look like:

```
import { helpers } from './your/path/to/helpers.js';
import React from 'react';

export const onClientEntry = () => helpers();
```

From the documentation:

> `onClientEntry` Function
>
> `(_: emptyArg, pluginOptions: pluginOptions) => undefined`
>
> Called when the Gatsby browser runtime first starts.

Comment: hi Ferran, after I moved the Helmet from inside BlogPostTemplate to in-between Layout and BlogPostTemplate, my whole blog page is gone. See my update.  Also `onClientEntry` won't work, as I have tried it already, the document says: `Called when the Gatsby browser runtime first starts.` so it only runs once but not on every page refresh.

Comment: The idea es to move the  `<Helmet>` as well as in `BlogTemplate` and `IndexPage` and remove it from the `<Layout>` since it's redundant. Can you debug what means "is gone"? In addition, the `onClientEntry` method, doesn't act if the page if it is called via routing (`<Link>` or `navigation`) but if it refreshes via URL or F5 or initial render it will load the function, that's why I said that I don't know if it fits your requirements but what we know as "page refresh" is inside the behaviour of the `onClientEntry method.`

Comment: thanks Ferran, I would like to leave the Layout there as a overall layout rather than repeat adding Layout to each different components e.g. About page component. I have solved this problem, please see my answer. `onClientEntry()` did not load the script for me when I was trying it by directly accessing a blog url e.g. `https://myblog.com/blogs/howtohike`. According to what you explained, it makes sense to me to use it in my case as well. I just exhausted about trying to fix problems for days. So for now, I will use my solution. next time, if the same issue hits, I will try yours. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using Hooks to import JavaScripts.

Also I have had a conclusion about when to import scripts under static folder and when not to do so.

In my scenario, the html components do not come from Reactjs component e.g. About.component.js , instead I create those html elements on the fly from Blog Editor provided by Netilify CMS.

So here is the tip: when html elements created from editors e.g. Netlify CMS's Markdown/Rich Editors, then I have to import Javascripts as-is(because otherwise the javascript functions will be uglified which leads to a different name, then you cannot reference it from the html elements you created inside the Netlify CMS Rich Editor) and the script files need to go under `static` folder. Otherwise you can do it as the normal way e.g. define your method in the Reactjs component and pass in it as a property and use it inside.

Here is how the ImportScript hook looks like:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const ImportMyScript = resourceUrl=> {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = resourceUrl;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [resourceUrl]);
};
export default ImportMyScript;
```

here is how to use it:

```
const BlogPost = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark: post } = data;
  ImportMyScript("../../bloghelpers.js");
  return (
  ............
  );
}
```

It makes sense to my scenario, as I only want to import abouthelpers.js on About page, bloghelpers.js on blog page.